# Extract and echo a URL parameter in WordPress

Tags: php, string, wordpress, parameters, get

On our WordPress site, I am linking from an email to a specific page.  Right now, an example of the link looks something like this:

www.example.com/?firstName=Joe&lastName=Smith&amount=$3,000

I would like to extract the parameters from the URL and echo them in different locations on the page.  For example, there is a paragraph that might say "Hi $firstName, you have been approved for $amount."

How would I do this in WordPress?

Comment: Can you show some code you already tried?

Answer (score 3):

The first step to accomplishing this is to define the URL parameters. You can do this in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('init','add_get_val');
function add_get_val() { 
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('firstName');
    $wp->add_query_var('lastName');
    $wp->add_query_var('amount');
}
```

Once this is done, you can query for these variables in your template:

```
if ( get_query_var('firstName') ) {
    echo get_query_var('firstName');
}

if ( get_query_var('lastName') ) {
    echo get_query_var('lastName');
}

if ( get_query_var('amount') ) {
    echo get_query_var('amount');
}
```