# Extract and Echo a URL parameter in wordpress using Avada theme

Tags: wordpress

On the WordPress site using Avada, My situation is very much similar to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40250428/12323081

They have given the code to be added into functions.php, As per my understanding the code should go in the child theme of Avada, but I don't understand where this part of the code will go?

(Which template file should this code be added to?)
Once this is done, you can query for these variables in your template:

```
if ( get_query_var('firstName') ) {
    echo get_query_var('firstName');
}

if ( get_query_var('lastName') ) {
    echo get_query_var('lastName');
}
```

Once added, how can these parameters be called on Front End?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It says - "The first step to accomplishing this is to define the URL parameters. You can do this in your functions.php file:" . In your child theme you will find functions.php file where you add first part.

Comment: I already did the first part, I am confused about the second one

Comment: Go to the template/function were you want to echo it and place the code

Comment: Seems there is no need to place the code for Avada

Answer (score 0):

After doing quite some R&D, there seems to be a very simple solution to get parameters from the URL in WP/Avada.

In order to achieve the result in my question, please use the Title element and then make use of the dynamic field  'Request Parameter' -> Param Type - Get -> Query Var - firstName

The image is attached for reference.
tinyurl.com/yy3vtwxq